# ASP.Net Core + .NET Framework Web API - frequent network errors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis, tcp

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.2 Web API targeting .NET framework 4.7.2 running under IIS, Out of Process. I am seeing a lot of *outgoing* network issues. The app connects to various things (SQL databases, SSAS via XMLA etc.) and I am seeing across the board network failures to connect to various resources. At first I thought it was SQL connections only but it appears to be network in general. I get some sort of failure very regularly, around 1 in 10 requests. I have this in web.config:

```
    <system.net>
      <connectionManagement>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="65535"/>
      </connectionManagement>
    </system.net>
```

and this in Startup.cs:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
```

However, it's not just HTTP connections that are failing, it's mostly SQL, SSAS, general TCP.

The failures are things like SQL error 26, unable to connect and similar for other non-SQL network resources. It is intermittent, there is hardly any load on the box at all. It seems to happen when API calls are made back to back perhaps.

I don't think it's a general network (router/switch) issue as I can set up, for example, a scripted console SQL connect/select/teardown to one of the remote services showing connect failures from the app and this never fails, even in a repeating loop running at the same time as I see errors in the app connecting to the same DB.
There must be some TCP/network tuning I am missing and would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: From cmd.exe >Ping IP (or Name).  The ping has options for long messages and different number of messages.  If you have internet issues ping will show errors. That is what ping is meant to do.

Comment: I can run successful ping continuously with no packet drop, even while the API app shows network errors.

Comment: With ping use options -t -l 65000 to give large amount of data.  Did you try both name and address?  The return times should be very consistent. The error does not seem to be in the TCP layer of the Network.  Sniffer data may show more info to help resolve.  The ping response is at the Network card and has no affect by the Application Layer.  So I suspect some other application(s) is affecting the results.  If a virus checker or firewall was checking port number that may cause these failures.  IP routing used is used by ping and port numbers are not checked.

Comment: I can try this but i can also run a script connecting to the same SQL db that fails to connect sometimes from the app every two seconds and this never fails.

Comment: It sound like you may have a timing issue getting the server name from the DNS Server. Does it fail using IP address or Computer Name (or both)?

Comment: Thanks to @jdweng - Interesting comment about larger ping packets - starting about 1500 bytes it starts to fail intermittently.

Comment: Now that is real interesting.  TCP maximum datagram size is also 1500 bytes.  So you are getting errors when packets size is > 1.  There is a IP header and TCP header.  The TCP specification is vague adding depending on Options different vendors interpreted the specification differently and the number of bytes of headers and data can vary.  But vendors are suppose to be able to handle the differences.   This goes back 50 years.  I will have to do more research.

Comment: Try other sizes around 1500 (larger and smaller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very unusual issue.  The reason to use large packets sizes is when you have a very small number of errors the more data you send the more errors you will get.  But the error rate should be constant.  You will always get errors.  But in this case the error are not constant.  The only start when data is split into more than one packet which occurs when you send data larger than 1500 bytes.

You probably have a multi-hop connection where the client and server are not directly connected by one cable.  You are going through routers and server which each have their own unique IP address (and name).

Normally errors are fixed by replacing cables or pieces of hardware.  You can either randomly start replacing hardware or you can use ping from/to different servers and routers to find which work and which gives error helping to isolate issue.

In you case it looks like the issues is one of your devices was not designed correctly.  Errors starting at 1500 bytes are usually due to vendor not fully testing devices and not fixing errors found during alpha and beta testing.  Most vendors do a very good job of testing and certifying their devices.  So this could be a "Made in China" issue.  Or maybe even a virus.  Still to fix issue start replacing or use ping to isolate which routes work and which give errors.

Comment: Well diagnosed, many thanks. We switched the VMESX host and the problem was solved and so it looks like it was indeed some low-level network error as you suspected. ping with larger packets is a useful tool.